# How to write a JUnit runner that runs a @BeforeCategory method before a TestCase in a @Category?

Tags: java, junit, junit-runner

I'm trying to write a specific JUnit Runner, and I did not find good tutorials / examples online.

The requirements are the following :

- I will have some categorized tests (e.g A.java from category catA, B.java from category catA, C.java from Category catC
- Each test has a single `@BeforeClass` method that needs to be run if the test is launched alone
- When launching all tests from the same category, the `@BeforeClass` method must only be launched once.
- Each @Test method from a Junit Test also has `@Before` and `@After` methods.

That being said, I looked at the different options available.

I started by creating `Test Suites` which would represent my test categories, using the provided junit Suite Runner. (`@RunWith(Suite.class)`)
You need to manually provide the `Tests` in the suite, using `@SuiteClasses()` which is annoying.

So I looked at the `ClasspathSuite` Runner, which allows to put all classes from the classpath in every suite, and filter them after with `@Category`

It also provides a `@BeforeSuite` annotation that is launched once when the suite is launched.

=> Everything is almost perfect.

- When a single test is launched, the `@BeforeClass` from this test is launched
- When a `Test Suite` is launched, the correct `Tests` are launched (thanks to the `@Category`), the `@BeforeSuite` is called only once, but the `@BeforeClass` of every Test is also called, where it should not.

=> All these things led me to think about implementing my own Runner.
I tried extending the ClasspathSuite Runner, but it is not designed to do so.
I tried extending the stock Suite Runner, but I did not succeed.

Could you help me understand how to implement these requirements in a JUnit Runner?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what your problems were with extending the `ClasspathSuite` and `Suite` runners? Also, doesn't `org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories` do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it without writing a runner? Instead, write a `@BeforeClass` method that uses a singleton list that records each before-category method that has been run in the current test run, and that knows how to run all the before-category methods (each probably in its own class). The `@BeforeClass` method determines its class's `@Category`, checks the list, and

- does nothing if that `@Category`'s before-category method has already run, or
- runs the before-category method and note in the list that that `@Category`'s method has been run.

Not requiring a custom runner is better because it will work in environments that provide their own runners, such as IDEs and continuous integration servers.

Comment: good point on providing a solution without a custom runner. It works like a charm